# Error message on failed to parse location

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, whatsapp

Hey I am currently working on automating WhatsApp in Python 3 using Selenium and so I wrote the code below:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

browser = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

browser.maximize_window()

browser.get("https://web.whatsapp.com/")

with open('group.txt', 'r', encoding='utf8') as f:
    groups = f.readlines

print(groups)
```

But I keep running into the error below, so is there something wrong with my code or is it just the chrome driver? This even happens when I tried to use gecko driver:

> File "", line 2, in raise_from
> urllib3.exceptions.LocationParseError: Failed to parse: http://127.0.0.1:35099/session

Comment: where is this `group.txt` located  ?

Comment: it is located on /home/lite/Documents/whatsapp-bot/group.txt

Comment: can you share the content of the file also, I will try to replicate the same in my local

Comment: the content of the file is "Anime.NET"

Comment: can you paste that here

Comment: it's only a single name

Comment: maybe you can try adding anything inside the .txt and see the result